# Xcode 6: can an iOS static library have a module map?

Tags: ios, xcode6, static-libraries

And then it could be linked and used from Objective-C with the

```
@import MyStaticLib;
```

syntax.

If so, how, *exactly*, do you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a static library with `.modulemap` file to use `@import` syntax

[[Create Objective-C static library]](https://Objective-C%20static%20library)

Answer (score -1):

If you can edit the library Xcode project you can create a [`*.modulemap` file](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Modules.html#module-map-language) and set it to the `MODULEMAP_FILE` Build Setting.

[Sample map file](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Framework/Desktop/Lumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.modulemap) from CocoaLumberjack:

```
framework module CocoaLumberjack {
    umbrella header "CocoaLumberjack.h"

    export *
    module * { export * }
}

module CocoaLumberjack.DDContextFilterLogFormatter {
    header "DDContextFilterLogFormatter.h"
    export *
}

module CocoaLumberjack.DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter {
    header "DDDispatchQueueLogFormatter.h"
    export *
}

module CocoaLumberjack.DDMultiFormatter {
    header "DDMultiFormatter.h"
    export *
}

module CocoaLumberjack.DDASLLogCapture {
    header "DDASLLogCapture.h"
    export *
}

module CocoaLumberjack.DDAbstractDatabaseLogger {
    header "DDAbstractDatabaseLogger.h"
    export *
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can by creating a **framework** from this static library, you can follow all the instructions [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios)

Once finished, you can import your static library like that:

```
@import MyStaticLib;
```